Ergonomic runtime-default args with Clap derive API
I've been using Clap's derive API but recently hit a case where I need some arguments' default to be determined at runtime.
A simplified version of my code is this, which is basically taken directly from
this documentation I found for how to combine the derive-based and Builder-based APIs in Clap.
#[derive(clap::Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = {".".to_string()})]
    repo: String,
    // (... other args with static defaults)
    #[command(flatten)]
    runtime_default: RuntimeDefaultArgs, 
}

struct RuntimeDefaultArgs {
    result_db: PathBuf,
    // (... other args with dynamic defaults)

}

impl FromArgMatches for RuntimeDefaultArgs {
    fn from_arg_matches(matches: &ArgMatches) -> Result<Self, clap::Error> {
        let mut matches = matches.clone();
        Self::from_arg_matches_mut(&mut matches)
    }
    fn from_arg_matches_mut(matches: &mut ArgMatches) -> Result<Self, clap::Error> {
        Ok(Self {
            result_db: matches.get_one::<PathBuf>("result-db").unwrap().to_owned(),
        })
    }
    fn update_from_arg_matches(&mut self, matches: &ArgMatches) -> Result<(), clap::Error> {
        let mut matches = matches.clone();
        self.update_from_arg_matches_mut(&mut matches)
    }
    fn update_from_arg_matches_mut(&mut self, matches: &mut ArgMatches) -> Result<(), clap::Error> {
        self.result_db = matches.get_one::<PathBuf>("result-db").unwrap().to_owned();
        Ok(())
    }
}

// This is where we actually define the arguments with dynamic defaults.
impl clap::Args for RuntimeDefaultArgs {
    fn augment_args(cmd: clap::Command) -> clap::Command {
        let default_db = calculate_default_db_path();
        cmd.arg(
            Arg::new("result-db")
                .long("result-db")
                .value_parser(value_parser!(PathBuf))
                .default_value(default_db.to_str()),
        )
    }
    fn augment_args_for_update(cmd: clap::Command) -> clap::Command {
        Self::augment_args(cmd)
    }
}

This is kinda OK for the current code, but now I want to add other subcommands, which will each have their own arguments with runtime-computed defaults. So it seems to follow this pattern I would need to implement these two repetitive traits again for each  subcommand.
Is there anything I'm missing here in Clap that would make this easier? It seems this problem is not at all present in the builder API. This kinda makes sense, since the derive API is fundamentally about doing stuff "at compile time" so from that PoV think mixing the derive and Builder APIs seems like the right direction. But maybe there's a more convenient way to do it?

The expression you pass to default_value_t doesn't have to be a constant.
For any argument type that implements the required traits, including Display, you could do this:
use std::path::PathBuf;
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(long, default_value_t = default_result_db())]
    pub result_db: String,
}

fn default_result_db() -> String {
    todo!();
}

Since PathBuf doesn't directly implement Display, you could make a wrapper:
use std::ops::Deref;
use clap::Parser;
use std::fmt::{self, Debug, Display, Formatter};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(long, default_value_t = default_result_db())]
    pub result_db: DisplayablePathBuf,
}

fn default_result_db() -> DisplayablePathBuf {
    todo!();
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DisplayablePathBuf(PathBuf);

impl FromStr for DisplayablePathBuf {
    type Err = <PathBuf as FromStr>::Err;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        PathBuf::from_str(s).map(Self)
    }
}

impl Debug for DisplayablePathBuf {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        Debug::fmt(&self.0, f)
    }
}

impl Display for DisplayablePathBuf {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        Display::fmt(&self.0.display(), f)
    }
}

impl Deref for DisplayablePathBuf {
    type Target = PathBuf;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &PathBuf {
        &self.0
    }
}


This is a helpful guidance. Additionally, the Debug is redundant. By implementing Display the standard library will automatically implement Debug as well.

@DavidGolembiowski thanks! I think you're confusing Debug with ToString, though. This doesn't compile. Also note, if you #[derive(Debug)], it doesn't simply call Display::fmt or <self.0 as Debug>::fmt(). It would produce DisplayablePathBuf(x) where x is <self.0 as Debug>::fmt().

Ah, you're right! I think I was confusing it with ToString. Thank you!

Oh nice, and now I realise that even in my own example I had default_value_t = {".".to_string()} - that doesn't seem like a constant expression so I should probably have realised the default_value_t gets evaluated at runtime!
